# UI-dialog overlay in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm using the [jQuery UI dialog modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) to show up form in a modal.

When tested in Chrome everything went well. But in Firefox the overlay (ui-widget-overlay) doesn't take the whole browser window. So when I scroll down when the modal is active the overlay is stopped and the rest of the webpage is visible...

Any help?

Comment: What is the version of the jQuery UI css file?

Comment: are you using [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) ?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot the url to the plugin. The version is 1.18.19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to the overlay css

```
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: great! worked like a charm. Why is the position absolute in the css of the dialog box? Strange that this works in chrome and not in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

For me does not solve the problem. Instead seems work correctly this other proposal [Dialog UI background problem in Firefox Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200000/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-stripe-issue).

In short:

> *[...] the background defined by jQuery UI is not just a solid color: it's an image [...]*

So you should replace background definition with something like `background-color: #000;`.

Please look at [link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200000/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-stripe-issue) to further details